# how to dynamically change css class for html form elements based on other css class

Tags: html, css

I want 
- a responsive form which have different layout for desktop and mobile

I have

- a form in html
- few responsive css classes from the gantry based template

  - gantry-width-## : defines a width based on current container
  - rt-floatleft : as name implies
  - hidden-desktop : hides the element in desktop
  - visible-desktop : hides the element in non-desktop

sample html

```
<form>
    <div class="gantry-width-40 rt-floatleft">
        <input class="gantry-width-70" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="clear hidden-desktop"></div>
    <br class="hidden-desktop" />
    <div class="gantry-width-40 rt-floatleft">
        <input class="gantry-width-70" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <br />
    <textarea class="gantry-width-70"></textarea>
</form>
```

here are some screens to give you an idea

desktop view

[image: desktop]

mobile view

[image: mobile]

as you can see that the text boxes are too small for the mobile view

note that screens are cropped to hide blank space on the right

The reason is that text-boxes are 70% size of the container which is 40% of it's parent, which is fine in desktop view as they are placed side by side, but in mobile view they are in separate rows

so what I am looking for is to change the parent container's width to 100% of the available area in mobile view.

So how can I change the class of the container i.e. `gantry-width-40` to `gantry-width-90` based on the css of `hidden-desktop` or `visible-desktop` class?

I prefer for css only solution, other's are welcome too.

Comment: rather than use the gantry-width classes, why not just use media queries and define the widths you want through either your own classes or specific styles?

Comment: @kinakuta, the gantry width classes are from fluid grid based on gantry framework that does uses media queries and several other factors. these are indeed required to maintain the consistency across the site. so I may not be able to redefine the widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use different classes? You can use mediaqueries.

I made this small example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

```
#parent {
    width: 50%;
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 5%;
}
#parent div {
    padding: 5%;
    background: lightgreen;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    #parent {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

What is does: when the viewport is bigger than 500px the media query doesn't apply, making the parent div 50% of the viewports width.

Then when you resize the viewport (or look with a device with viewport smaller than 500px), the media query does apply. Making the parent div take up 90% of the width.

I created a JSFiddle for you, [**check here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/g1trsjbw/). Resize the result window to see what happens.

Comment: result is exactly what I am looking for. in a way my sample also behave the same. but the problem starts when the element shifts from a column to next row. is it possible to change the width based on `hidden-desktop` or `visible-desktop` class?

Comment: `hidden-desktop` should be visible when the screen is smaller, add it to the media query part: `.hidden-desktop { display: block; }`

Comment: that make sense, btw is it possible to use the value defined in `gantry-width-%%` classes as the width for parent? as I may not be able to hard-code the same to a value.

Comment: Your idea helped me solve the issue, but I used a bit different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered on using a CSS framework? I recommend you Zurb Foundation, the area you are looking for is this http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Comment: there is some framework in place, whole site is responsive, only issue is I am not able to figure out the correct usage. the site is based on joomla and gantry framework.